# regEx replace not removing spaces as expected

Tags: regex, vba, excel

Here is the typical string I am working with:

```
·         Identify & document site-related constraints and assumptions.
```

I would like to scrub that string to get rid  of everything before "Identify"...

I wrote a function to take the string and scrub it, here it is:

```
Function dataScrub(dataIn As String)
Dim dataIn_orig As String
dataIn_orig = dataIn

'BEGIN : create and set regular expression
Dim regEx
Set regEx = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
With regEx
        .IgnoreCase = True
        .MultiLine = False
        .Pattern = "^[\s]*[·]+[\s]*"
        .Global = True
End With

dataScrub = regEx.Replace(dataIn_orig, "")
End Function
```

For an unknown reason, the replace is replacing the · (not a period, more like a bullet) but not getting rid of the spaces that follow it, so my end result is:

```
      Identify & document site-related constraints and assumptions.
```

When I test my regEx using an online tester (http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascriptexample.html), it works as intended.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I don't think your issue is with the regex, but with the formatting of the text.  I am playing with something to see if I can get it to work.  I noticed this because, the excel trim function will not remove the spaces in front of the text after the regex is run

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[\s]` matches either a `\` or an `s`. Try using just plain old `\s` without the square braces.

---

Well, since that still doesn't work, the last `\s*` might be a reluctant match instead of a greedy one. You should be able to fix that by adding a `\b` to the end of your expression. `\b` indicates a word boundary (either before or after a word). Give this one a try:

```
^\s*[·]+\s*\b
```

Comment: i tried removing the brackets to no prevail, thank you for the suggestion though

Comment: adding the \b did not work either.
of note though, it did work (as my first attempt did) in http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascriptexample.html but interestingly, did not work in http://rubular.com/ (whereas my first one did), not like any of that actually matters though :)

Comment: Are you sure the spaces are being matched by the `\s`? The space might not actually be a typical tab or space. It might be some fancy formatting instead, which a regular expression can't match. I'd advise copying the field from Excel and into a text editor, saving it, then examining the result in a hex editor to see what character(s) is actually causing that space to appear after the dot.

Comment: great idea...
i did what you suggested, here is the hex breakdown:
B7 = the bullet
A0 = the white space ( x7)
20 = the white space immediately preceding the word "Identify"

time for me to look up how to incorporate hex values into Excel VB regEx's (if it is possible)

Comment: FTW!
doing regEx's with HEX was pretty easy after a quick google search. Welbox, thank you very much for you time assisting me!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the answer has been accepted already, but running this line of code in your function will take care of you issue as well.

```
Cells.Replace What:=Chr(160), Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart
```

Comment: thank you, i will consider trying that approach in the future